# How to add a table view Controller to Tab Bar Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

I am using storyboard for all ui layout creation.

I have a table view controller that I have removed on load of application using below code as for normal users one tab bar item need to be hidden.

```
self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.remove(at: 4)
```

But when Admin logs in(I am checking by comparing the email auth) the above removed table view controller should be added, so when I am adding using  the below code

```
self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.insert(AdminProductUploaderTableVC(), at: 4)
```

is only adding blank white space.
`AdminProductUploaderTableVC` have navigation controller on Storyboard.

So how to load a existing table view controller for admin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong ?

```
self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.insert(AdminProductUploaderTableVC(), at: 4)
```

is creating object like this  `AdminProductUploaderTableVC()` instead of loading from storyboard.

First Goto Storyboard and add storyboard identifier  to `AdminProductUploaderTableVC`

Go to   `AdminProductUploaderTableVC` and add Following method

```
class func viewController() -> AdminProductUploaderTableVC {
    return UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AdminProductUploaderTableVC") as! AdminProductUploaderTableVC
}
```

Now Replace your line with

```
self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.insert(UINavigationController(rootViewController:AdminProductUploaderTableVC.viewController()), at: 4)
```

Hope it is helpful

Comment: this works as the the new Admin VC is loading up correctly. Thanks for that.

Comment: One thing that doesn't load properly is that the Tab bar item image and Selected image is not loading as set in Storyboard for AdminProductUploaderVC..